# How does Shield of missile attraction work with friendly fire?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ranged-attack, shield, curses

Let's say the tank is attuned to the shield of missile attraction and a fellow team member fires a bow/crossbow at an enemy within 10ft of said tank. Does the team member's projectile hit the tank instead of the intended enemy?

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag since the behavior you describe matches the description of the 5e shield of missile attraction curse. Is that the correct edition?

Answer (score 15):

#### The shield doesn’t care. You are now the target.

The shield of missile attraction description states:

> Whenever a ranged weapon attack is made against a target within 10 feet of you, the curse causes you to become the target instead.

Nothing here is said about who made the attack or who the target is. The shield doesn’t care. You become the target any time *anything*, creature or object, within ten feet of you is targeted by a ranged weapon attack from *any* source.